# COTS solutions for ±18V DC (or even ±20V) and ±30V PCB-mounted power supplies in the 3-5 Watt range

Tags: power-supply

Most manufacturers make DC-DC converters with only ±15V or ±24V outputs for driving opamps. Opamps generally fall in several max-DC-supply classes. Typical are the ±22V ones (e.g. LM741 and a ton more), some of which do have reliable operation up to ±20V (e.g. the LM741A). Alas DC-DC converters in between ±15V and ±24V (e.g. ±18V) are extremely boutique items than can be very hard to source. So, what are practical solutions for building your own (on par with COTS devices in terms of characteristics) wile using as few components as possible? A ±9V with voltage doublers for example is a practical solution?

The same question applies to ±30V sources that would be useful for getting most output swing out of an OPA551 for example (which has its characteristics given at this supply voltage, by the way.)

Comment: you can get various voltages very easily, but what kind of power are we talking about? A few milliamps, or amps?

Comment: Like I said in the title, I'm concerned with supplies in the 3-5 Watt range. This would mean 100-250mA at the most.

Comment: Lol sorry, must have missed that when reading.. you can build your own adjustable buck/boost/negative supplies with reasonably low amount of components (the lowest is usually around 4 external components needed, most are about 8-9, some get really crazy with a lot more but they are usually high power external switch controllers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're doing the sort of thing that can live without galvanic isolation, there are plenty of easy solutions. If you don't mind a transformer, here is one of the lowest parts-count (and probably lowest cost) solutions, using the ubiquitous [LM2577](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2577.pdf):

[image]

The simpler solutions (as with the cheaper DC-DC converters) tend to have so-so regulation, require a minimum load etc. Be mindful of this if you're up near the absolute maximum voltage input of the load semiconductors- the output voltage could be volts above nominal with a very light load.

Comment: If anybody wants to do a bit of background reading on what goes inside the LM2577 and similar "simpler switcher" chips, there's a (rather forgotten) 1995 paper by a Nat Semi employee http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4757-2353-3_15 Being published in an academic venue it also compares them with similar solutions from LTC and SGS-Thompson (now ST). It doesn't look like this paper was republished as a Nat Semi (or TI) app note though.